# How can I decrypt encrypted files using a PEM private key?

Tags: perl, pki, pem

I have files which have either been encrypted with a public key and the Blowfish algorithm, or a public key and the AES-256 algorithm.

I'm looking to put together a Perl script that would be able to use the private keys (which I do have) to decrypt the files.

The public and private key files are all in PEM format, and while I can find ways of reading the PEM files, and ways of decrypting data with a key, I haven't yet found a way of going from PEM -> key.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you trying to figure out which key to use to decrypt a particular file? You said that you already know how to decrypt the data.

Comment: I know that I need to use one of the private keys, and I've seen modules like Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA, Crypt::OpenSSL::AES and Crypt::Blowfish.  With ::RSA, I've worked out how to encrypt/decrypt data  (and I think that it should be very similar to use ::AES)... but they require a key to set up the cipher object.

It's getting that key out of the PEM files that I've not worked out...

Comment: So is it fair to say that your question is really "How do I determine which private key to use to decrypt a PEM message?", and not the title that you used?

Comment: maybe... but once I can work out how to go from the (a) PEM private key to a key that I can use to create the cipher object, I'll be able to get things working.
Maybe the question should have been "How do I get from a private PEM key to a key to use with a Crypt::* module"

Answer (score 1):

Isn't PEM just a base64 encoding (wrapped in `--- BEGIN/END CERTIFICATE ---` lines)? Try the [`Mime::Base64`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Mime::Base64) module, or have a look at the source to the [`Convert::PEM`](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/BTROTT/Convert-PEM-0.07/lib/Convert/PEM.pm) module.

Comment: It does seem to be a Base64 encoding, and Convert::PEM is doing a decode_base64.

If I try to use the decoded value though with Crypt::OpenSSL::AES, I'm getting "The key must be 128, 192 or 256 bits long".  I guess my key is longer than that...

So I need do something else to it... but I'm not currently just whether it's just a case of taking the first 256(?) bits or not.